# Jquery see if iframe location has changed

Tags: javascript, html

So I want to check if and I frame location has changed

```
function myFunction()
{
  setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);

  if (document.getElementById("myiframe").src = 'http://www.constant-creative.com/login';)
  {
  } 
  else 
  {
    $( "#loginframe" ).hide();
  }
}
```

That is what I have so far

Comment: Use `==` for a comparison operator

Comment: Or even better (faster), `===`

Comment: how would I fix this?
 setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);

Answer (score 1):

In javascript, `=` is an [assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators). For example

```
// foo can be whatever
foo = 'bar'
// now foo is 'bar'
```

But if you want to compare things, use the [comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) `==` (equality operator), or `===` (strict equality operator). The difference is that `==` compares only the value, and `===` compares the value and the type. For example

```
var a = 1;
a ==  1;     // yes
a === 1;     // yes
a ==  true;  // yes
a === true;  // NO!
// a is still 1
```

If you want to negate a comparison operator (i.e, know if two things are different), you can use `!=` and `!==`. For example,

```
1 !=  1;     // no
1 !== 1;     // no
1 !=  true;  // no
1 !== true;  // YES!
```

If you know that the types of the things you are comparing are the same, then `==` and `===` will have the same behavior, but `===` will be faster.

---

In your case, you could use something like

```
function myFunction()
{
  if (document.getElementById("myiframe").src
      !==
      'http://www.constant-creative.com/login';
  ) {
    $( "#loginframe" ).hide();
  }

  setTimeout(myFunction,3000);
}
myFunction();
```